# Objective-C UISwitch change state of another UISwitch

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch

Could anyone please show me how I can make one UISwitch affect the state of another UISwitch?

Thanks!
B.

Comment: When you get the UISwitch valued changed: `BOOL fisrtIsOn = [yourFirstSwitch isOn]`;, you can do: `[yourSecondSwitch fisrtIsOn]` or `[yourSecondSwitch setOn:!fisrtIsOn]`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add event handler for your switch1 value changed, you can do it in storyboard as well):

```
[switch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Implement method and change value of other switch:

```
-(void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{
    UISwitch *s = (UISwitch*)sender;
    //Change value on second switch
    [s2 setOn:!s.isOn];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to confirm I wasn't barking up the wrong tree

Answer (score 0):

consider you having two switches, switch1 and switch 2.

then,

```
//in  viewDidLoad

[ self.Switch1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(switchChanged:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(void)switchChanged:(uiSwitch*)sender

{

    if([sender isOn]) //check whether switch1 is on
    {
         if([self.switch2 isOn]) //turn switch2 off 
         {
              [self.switch2 setOn:NO];
         }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you